# UI is blocking after 10 trips of three view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, memory-management

i have 3 view controllers let say VC1->VC2->VC3 through navigation controller. In VC3, I am trying to pop back to VC1 & again navigating by process VC1->VC2->VC3. While going from one view controller to other the following code is used

```
-(void)NEXTButtonpressed:(id)sender
{
    PaymentVC *paymentview=[[PaymentVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"PaymentVC" bundle:Nil];

    if (![[[OSEsingleton sharedInstance].globaldictionary objectForKey:@"status"]boolValue])
    {

        if ([self validationforsupportersname])
        {
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:paymentview animated:YES];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:paymentview animated:YES];
    }
}
```

After 10 cycles my UI gets freezed, and sometimes I am getting the following errors.

1)

```
levanApp(852,0x366279dc) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=65536) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
(Occuring Frequently)
```

2)

```
levanApp[852] <Error>: ImageIO: PNG insufficient memory
(Occuring Rarely)
```

Sometimes app is crashing and showing 58% cpu time in the following code `imageWothocontentofFile` call

```
-(UIImage *)returnlogoimgae:(NSString *)imagename
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",imagename];
    NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
    NSLog(@"%@",getImagePath);
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];
    return image;
}
```

I have used time profile for it. In one  method call `[_coredata parseTheCoreData:results]` i am getting 100% CPU time. How can i handle this issue?

Comment: can you please show me your code when click or any action to push controller.

Comment: please see my updated code nextButtonPressed.

Comment: It looks like you are running out of memory - did you profile for that too? If that assumption is correct, you will need to post more code, because you will probably have a retain cycle somewhere

Comment: why aren't you using segues to move around?

Comment: i will check for retain cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it seems you forgot to go back! That means you are heaping all those view controllers onto the stack until you are out of memory.

First call

```
[navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

(Make all the push view controller calls non-animated except the last one.)

Comment: at vc3 i am doing same thing . i mentioned in second line .

Comment: According to the posted code, you are not doing it.